# How does python load Boost.Python libraries?

Tags: python, shared-libraries, boost-python

Considering the following archetypal Boost.Python module, which brings a class "D" from a separate C++ header file.

```
/* file: a/b.cpp */
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(c)
{
    class_<d>("D")
}
```

When I compile this to a shared library, I'm confused how I can expose it to Python.

1. What should I call the library? a.so? liba.so? b.so? libb.so?
2. Where does the library need to be? Can I leave it in a subdirectory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We prefer to call the library `_c.so`, put it in a module, and then add an `__init__.py` that basically does `from _c import *`.  So you have:

- `package`

  - `_c.so`
  - `__init__.py`